# Reporting on contribution amounts when added to a membership page

Tags: civimember, contributions, reports, financial-types

We've added the option to accept additional donations when initiating or renewing a membership by enabling the Contribution Amounts section on a contribution page but there doesn't seem to be a way to report on these additional contributions. For example, if a member renews a family membership for $35 and makes a $20 donation, Civi records a $55 membership. We then have to go through each membership and each contribution to figure out how much they donated along with their membership fee. We've tried the ExtendedReport extension which has some great ways to view Price Set info but we can't use contribution price sets on membership pages :-(. Has anyone figured out a way to get this info into a report?

cheers ... :) gn

Comment: "we can't use contribution price sets on membership pages". To clarify. Do you mean that when you use a Price Set for a membership page (which you can) that you cannot get something you need working? or that if you do use a Price Set that the ExtReport does not help. not quite clear

Comment: We're taking additional contributions as part of the membership and if you enable a price set on the Amounts page you get the error: "You cannot enable both a Contribution Price Set and Membership Signup on the same online contribution page." We've considered adding the additional donation options to the Membership price set but we may still run into the reporting problem - how much of the transaction was membership vs. donation?

Comment: i would do the latter. single price set. memberships. add the donation line item there with its own financial type. then the Extended Report extension should solve your last issue of how much is donation v member fee

Comment: I think I found the key: this help text is behind the Financial type on the Contribution page - "NOTE: If you are using this contribution page for membership signup and renewals, the financial type configured in the membership type settings will be used when recording the membership payment. The financial type selected here will only be used if you are also collecting additional contributions ..." Since I had both set as Membership, the contributions also reported as Membership. Going to try this change first and then consolidated Price Set if this doesn't work - cheers ... :) gn

Comment: The 16 December modification didn't help - it simply lumped the entire transaction in to the Donation financial type and was equally unreportable. As mentioned above by @petednz, the Price Set with line items dedicated specifically to financial types of Member Dues and Donations seems to be the only way to get reporting on contribution pages which include both membership signup and donation options. - :) gn

Comment: Geof, i added my suggestion as an answer - if you could +1 and/or Accept so it helps others. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would do the following. use a single price set based on Memberships. add the donation line item in to it with its own financial type.

then the [Extended Report](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport) extension should solve your last issue of how much is donation v member fee

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to come in here after so long, but I've been tearing my hair out trying to figure out how to have CiviCRM do something as seemingly simple as accept a membership amount, and make its financial type "Membership" and a donation and make it's financial type "Donation". All on the same Contribution page.

And I just don't understand the above solutions. WE can't create a price set that has Memberships and Donations in it. But when I create a Contribution form with the form contribution type set to Donation, and have a membership also being taken, it will only show one financial type. The donation.

(I am using Stripe, so it can't do two charges. WHich is fine, since that would cost us two times the fixed transaction fee)

from petednz - fuzion

> single price set. memberships. add the donation line item there with its own financial type.

Add the donation line where? The error says we can't add it in the price set. So where is this donation line going?

Forgive my irritation, but this seems like such a fundamental REQUIREMENT in ANY country and in ANY tax system, that the sheer difficulty of making it happen is mind boggling.

Comment: We were able to make it work quite nicely using @petednz-fusion's suggestion:
1. Install Edit Line Item Extension extension
2. Install Extended Reports extension
3. Create a price set with your options and financial types as desired. E.g. our membership price set is Membership (fintype=Membership), Donation-Fixed ($25,$50,$100; fintype=Donation), Donation-Other (fintype=Donation)
4. Add the price set to your Membership Contribution Page on the Memberships tab. Don't enable contributions on the Amounts tab - the system won't let you do both.

Comment: 5. Line item details will now appear on extended reports that you create and on the Contributions dashboard.

We don't get line item details from our transaction provider (PayPal) to load to Quickbooks since we're using the basic PayPal integration but we can now reconcile, and categorize, transactions using the CiviCRM reports :-)

cheers - :) gn

Comment: Hmmm.... Whats the Edit Line Item extension? I don't see any mention of that by anyone until you mention it. I did indeed eventually work out that a price set can be used to hold the membership and the donation. Very confusing. But I know nothing about the Edit Line Item Extension. Maybe that's the missing piece....

Thanks for the reply and the walk through.

Comment: It lets you view and edit Line Items on the CiviCRM backend. Extremely useful if you're entering checks that come in with multiple category splits. See https://civicrm.org/extensions/line-item-editor